# Oracle SQL - Insertion with subquery returning multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I've an issue with a n-n relationship while trying to insert in the "middle table".

The goal is to associate `Commune` and `ZipCode` (in France, a Commune is a city, and the city name can have multiple ZipCode because there are commune with the same name. But not in the same place)

And a ZipCode can handle multiple City, here is my n-n relationShip.

So here is the request i use :

```
INSERT INTO FR(IDCODEPOSTAL, IDCOM_SIM) 
VALUES 
('24209 CEDEX', (SELECT DISTINCT IDCOM_SIM FROM COMMUNE WHERE NCCENR='Creysse'));
```

But here the SELECT returns 2 rows. I've read much but I didn't find a way to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but usually you'd use an `INSERT ... SELECT` (without the `VALUES`) to insert multiple rows with a single statement:

```
INSERT INTO FR
  (IDCODEPOSTAL, IDCOM_SIM) 
VALUES 
 SELECT '24209 CEDEX', IDCOM_SIM 
 FROM COMMUNE 
 WHERE NCCENR='Creysse';
```

If you however want to insert only a single row, you need to make sure the sub-select returns only one. This is usually done using an aggregate function such as `max()`

```
INSERT INTO FR
  (
    IDCODEPOSTAL, 
    IDCOM_SIM
  ) 
VALUES 
  (
    '24209 CEDEX', 
    (SELECT max(IDCOM_SIM) FROM COMMUNE WHERE NCCENR='Creysse')
  );
```